# Framework laravel php erro na pasta vendor

Tags: php, laravel

Quando abro o meu projeto no framework laravel que é na linguagem de programação em php,

tem erro na pasta vendor,

qualquer projeto que eu crio no framework tem esse erro

O caminho do erro no projeto é:

/vendor/phpunit/php-code-coverage/tests/_files/Crash.php

a linha que está com erro no arquivo Crash.php é :[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [erro na pasta vendor no framework laravel](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/466095/erro-na-pasta-vendor-no-framework-laravel)

Answer (score -1):

Isso se dá pois sua IDE está tentando fazer a leitura de alguma dependência mas por algum motivo não está compreendendo.
Tente instalar na sua IDE algum módulo/extensão de lint do PHP.
Outra sugestão é usar o VSCode que uma IDE incrível pra trabalhar com PHP e tem diversas extensões incríveis.

Comment: Coloquei o código no visual studio. Também atualizei o php . Porém, continua o mesmo erro.